# Problem with a table - error "There is no line here to end"

Tags: tables

the below table gives me error "Line 237 There is no line here to end"
What is the problem here?

```
 237   \begin{center}
    \textbf{\textit{90$\%$ confidence interval}}:\\\\*
    \begin{tabular}{| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |}
    \hline
    Number of Paths & 10000 & 40000 & 90000 & 160000 \\ \hline
    Number of Steps & 100 & 200 & 300 & 400 \\ \hline
    Upper Estimate &  8.4891  &  8.3498  &  8.3495 & 8.3479 \\ \hline
    Lower Estimate &  8.0824  &  8.1482  &   8.2147 & 8.2466\\ \hline
    Heston Call Price & 8.2857  &  8.2490  &  8.2753 & 8.2972\\ \hline
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \hline
```

Comment: Are those really `1`s for your column specifications? They should be one of `l`, `r`, `c` or `p{<len>}`, but not `1`. Also, you have an out-of-`tabular` `\hline` dangling at the bottom of your code snippet - most certainly an (unrelated) error as well.

Comment: I corrected those and still have an error, "There's no line to end here"

Comment: You're using `\\\\*` in your second line. That should cause the error - what do you ant to achieve there? We can fix that :)

Comment: it is not my code but I need to implement this into my document

Comment: it should give me a plain table

Comment: You're using much too many lines, I will extend my answer with a nice table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't end an empty line, so `\\\\` causes an error because the second line break tries to end an empty line.

If you just want one free line use

```
\\[\baselineskip]
```

Though i think you would like to have a new paragraph there, the unse

```
\par
```

instead. Or use `table` environment to have a floating table including a title and such (which I prefer for tables).

*Update* Concerning the OPs request, here's a complete example employing the wonderful `booktabs` package. One question would be: Do the columns have names?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}\centering
        \begin{tabular}{lllll}\toprule
        Number of Paths & 10000 & 40000 & 90000 & 160000 \\
        Number of Steps & 100 & 200 & 300 & 400 \\
        Upper Estimate &  8.4891  &  8.3498  &  8.3495 & 8.3479 \\
        Lower Estimate &  8.0824  &  8.1482  &   8.2147 & 8.2466\\
        Heston Call Price & 8.2857  &  8.2490  &  8.2753 & 8.2972\\\bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{90$\%$ confidence interval}\label{tab:trials}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

This yields a floating table that can be referred to by `\ref{tab:trials}`. It looks like

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, I noticed that even though the document was not going through in the editor when printing pdf  the updated version of pdf was still saved, how is this possible?

Comment: If you have errors in your document there are cases where the document is still build. For example when you're using an unknown command in math mode, e.g. `\mySymbol` there's just an empty space at that point, you get an error, but still a typeset document.